# Determining the way the IPv6 interface identifier was created

Tags: ipv6, tracking

In IPv6 the 64bit interface identifier of an IPv6 address can be determined in one of 3 ways:

1. Stateless Address Autoconfiguration: put in the MAC address of the NIC (+ FF:FE and  flip a bit).
2. Privacy Extensions for Stateless Address Autoconfiguration: Effectively choose a "random" value.
3. Use DHCPv6 to explicitly specify the address.

For analytics purposes I would like to know which of these was used.

For the first case (which I expect to be used the most) I would start by looking at a combination of the "FF:FE" and looking for known MAC prefixes.
But is it the most accurate way of doing this?

Is there a relatively reliable way to determine which of these is used when I only have the resulting IPv6 address (like in a webserver logfile)? 
Or is doing an educated guess (like what I mentioned above) the best I can hope for?

P.S. Perhaps someone knows of "ready to run" code sample that does such a classification "as best as possible" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the same LAN, you can compare the identifier with the host's Ethernet MAC address, to see if they match. But aside from that – especially if the host is behind one or more routers – an educated guess is the best you can get. The host is free to choose *any* identifier for its addresses (including even other hosts' MAC addresses), as long as it remains unique within the subnet.